# How do I display a decimal to a max of two zeroes after the point

Tags: c#

for example.

If I have the decimal

> 123.4567

I want the string

> 123.4567

but if I have the decimal

> 123.4000000

I want the string

> 123.40

Note, this is not rounding, I just don't want to end up with decimal strings with 4 zeroes after the point every time when I convert it to a string.

Comment: Lots of info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx. Google is your friend.

Comment: I hope you are using `decimal` and not `double`/`float` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
myDecimal.ToString("0.00##");
```

This will give a max of 4 digits after the decimal. Adjust the number of `#`'s to get the wanted number of max decimal digits.